# Thought question was answered, but MWE now behaves as originally

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently posed a LaTeX question:

[Adding different entities to a table of contents, part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192392/adding-different-entities-to-a-table-of-contents-part-2)

I thought it was answered and now can't get the MWE to work.  I don't know what happened.  Should I post as a new question, or modify the original question?

I tried to write a quick comment on the answer but the system won't let me.

Should I just pose as a new question?

Comment: Related: [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)

Comment: Which question and did you update your TeX distro in the meantime?

Comment: No, I did nothing to my distribution.  I can't figure out what happened.

Comment: @Dov: Obviously it is my answer to that question and I would like to know, why the MWE does not work. I tried my solution, as published and it compiles without complains or errors. Could you be more specific what fails?

Comment: I just re-pasted your code into mwe.tex on my machine.  I built the pdf, and what I see is a header Chapter 1 on every page, including lab 1: and lab 2:.  This question asked how to defeat printing the header for chapters on pages that are labs.  I would extend that to any content that is equivalent to a chapter, like Appendices.

Comment: @Dov: I edited the answer, introducing a pagestyle called `lab` for those 'sections'